What does the notation $d'$ mean?
$\text{I was studying helmotz theorem and saw this notation, what does it mean? How is d}\tau' \, \text{ different from d}\tau \text{?}$

From :- David J. Griffiths-Introduction to Electrodynamics-Addison-Wesley (2012) : Appendix C

Pages 58-60 of Griffiths Electrodynamics give you enough context to figure that it is the volume element of the charge distribution $dq = \rho d \tau'$ due to the vector $\bf{r}'$ as it moves over the entire charge volume.

I have used my moderator superpower to reopen this question, because I wasted an entire day trying to figure out exactly this question when I was an undergraduate. Griffiths almost certainly defines the notation somewhere, but other authors are not so generous.

The differential $\mathrm d\tau$ is commonly used to indicate a volume interval. In an elementary calculus course you might emphasize that it's a volume by writing out $\mathrm dx\ \mathrm dy\ \mathrm dz$, but that particular notation implies Cartesian coordinates, while the actual coordinate system might be irrelevant. Other authors might write $\mathrm d^3\vec r$.
The prime arises because we care about all of space twice. We want to be able to find $U$ and $\vec W$ anywhere in space, but each of them depends on charges and currents everywhere in space. We have the source distribution over $\vec r'$, which disappears when we integrate it. Griffiths hides the $\vec r$ in his cursive r, which I don't know offhand how to type.

"The prime arises because we care about all of space twice" Can you please elaborate? I don't quite understand that.

Hmmm, I just rewrote and erased the same thing that I already had in my answer. Another explanation: when you do a definite integral like $\int_a^b 2x\ \mathrm dx= b^2-a^2$, the $x$ is gone afterward. It is a "dummy variable" whose name doesn't really matter, because it only exists under the integral sign. These are definite integrals, even though "over all space" hasn't been written next to the integral symbol anywhere. But there are so many symbols floating around that Griffiths still wants to use something like an "r" for the dummy variable under the integral. The choice here is $r'$.
